# What is the type of XMLHttpRequest in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, safari, xmlhttprequest

I wonder what the standard type of the `XMLHttpRequest` object is in JavaScript. I have found different results depending on the engine.

In Firefox and Chrome:

```
typeof XMLHttpRequest //=> "function"
```

In Safari:

```
typeof XMLHttpRequest //=> "object"
```

The W3C specification uses the `interface` keyword to define `XMLHttpRequest`, [which is not used in practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29600602/2050):

```
[Constructor(optional XMLHttpRequestOptions options)]
interface XMLHttpRequest : XMLHttpRequestEventTarget {
  // ...
}
```

The [MDN definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) states that:

> XMLHttpRequest is a JavaScript object...

But Firefox returns `"function"`, so the term is vague at least. The definition also states as for now that:

> It's now being standardized in the W3C.

I have looked a bit more here and there, but no *definitive answer*™. Is there any?

*Beyond this point, some extra background*

---

#### Context of the question

I have just fixed a bug in this code:

```
if (typeof XMLHttpRequest === "function") {
  // do something
}
```

The bug occurred only in Safari 7 so far (no test on other versions). The code works fine in Firefox and Chrome. The fix was:

```
if (typeof XMLHttpRequest !== "undefined") {
  // do something
}
```

The problem came from assuming that `typeof XMLHttpRequest` is the same everywhere...

Comment: Practically speaking it's exposed to Javascript as a constructor function.  Keep in mind that functions in Javascript are also objects and can contain properties too.  It might help to know what you're really trying to figure out because whether it reports typeof as "function" or "object" is really immaterial.  Either way, you can call it as a constructor and it can have properties.

Comment: Not directly related, but won't `XMLHttpRequest || ActiveXObject` throw a ReferenceError if `XMLHttpRequest` is not defined?

Comment: @jfriend00: This is what OP is saying - in Safari, it is curiously not a function. `XMLHttpRequest instanceof Function === false`. I always thought a constructor must be a function. (Verified, Safari 8.0.6)

Comment: Host objects sometimes follow strange rules and seem to have the weakest standardization.  They aren't pure Javascript objects - they are host objects exposed via Javascript.  The work-around is to not assume it's one specific type and test for not being `undefined`.

Comment: @jfriend00: Ain't that the truth. Breaking news: browsers have incompatibilities. :P

Comment: Thanks all for raising relevant points. The goal of the question is to leave some traces about this discrepancy, so that someone somewhere gets some light. JavaScript is amazingly flexible. Still, homogeneity helps.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara You are right (flushing).

Comment: It seems this is the case for all native constructors in Safari; `typeof Image`, `typeof Location`, `typeof History` are all `"object"`. I don't know if or how it's related, but the `constructor` and `__proto__` properties are a plain `Object` constructor/instances in Safari, but a constructor in Firefox.

Comment: Does this code really need to work in an environment where neither `XMLHttpRequest` or `ActiveXObject` is defined?  How old a browser would that have to be?  Perhaps it's just time to remove that `if` statement entirely.  There are probably bigger fish to fry if there's no ajax of any kind.

Comment: @jfriend00 Agreed, the context is debatable. Does it help to frame the actual question if I remove the context section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Safari appears to be wrong here, according to ECMAScript 5 and the Web IDL spec. `typeof XMLHttpRequest` should return `"function"`.

The [WebIDL spec says](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebIDL/#interface-object):

> If the interface is declared with a `[Constructor]` extended attribute, then the interface object can be called as a function to create an object that implements that interface.
>
> ...
>
> The internal `[[Call]]` method of the interface object behaves as follows...

Meanwhile, the [specification for `typeof` in the ESCAScript 5 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3) has a return-value table with the entries:

> Object (native or host and does implement `[[Call]]`) : **`"function"`**
>
> Object (host and does not implement `[[Call]]`) : Implementation-defined except may not be **`"undefined"`**, **`"boolean"`**, **`"number"`**, or **`"string"`**.

From this table, we can see that any object -- native or host -- that implements `[[Call]]` is required to cause `typeof` to yield `"function"`. The WebIDL spec requires `[Constructor]` interface objects to implement `[[Call]]`, so they should yield `"function"`.

Comment: Yeah, Safari has just another host-object bug

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to check that `XMLHttpRequest` exists then you can use:

```
if (typeof XMLHttpRequest !== "undefined") {
  // do something
}
```

or

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest !== undefined) {
  // do something
}
```

or

```
if (this.XMLHttpRequest !== undefined) {
  // do something
}
```